# Getting the value upon match from the ref table

Tags: sql, join

I have 2 tables

[image]

```
Select distinct 
     ID
    ,ValueA
    ,Place (How to get the Place value from the table 2 based on the Match between        2 columns ValueA and ValueB 
Here Table2 is just a ref Table I''m using)
    ,Getdate() as time
Into #Temp
From Table1
```

For example when we receive value aa in ValueA column - I want the value of "Place" =  "LA"
For example when we receive value bb in ValueA column - I want the value of "Place" =  "TN"

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What database engine are you using so we can give more exact syntax? SQL Server? PostgreSQL? MySQL? MS Access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT   A.ID
       , A.ValueA
       , B.Place
       , GETDATE()   INTO #TempTable
FROM   Table1 A INNER JOIN Table2 B
ON     A.ValueA = B.ValueB
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this dude:

Select ID, ValueA, Place, getdate() as Date FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 on Table1.ValueA = table2.ValueB.

Hope this works dude!!!

Regards...

Answer (score 1):

```
Select 
     t1.ID
    ,t1.ValueA
    ,t2.Place
    ,Getdate() as time
Into #Temp
From Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.ValueA = t2.ValueB
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are looking to do an inner join:

```
SELECT Table1.ID, Table1.ValueA, Table2.Place
FROM Table1
INNER JOIN Table2 ON Table1.ValueA = Table2.ValueB
```

Assumption: `ValueB` on table 2 is the primary key (or at least `UNIQUE` and therefore a candidate key).

Also, the `DISTINCT` is redundant assuming that `ID` is a primary key. Furthermore, you more than likely do not need a temporary table since a join can be used as an inner `SELECT` in most databases.

The exact syntax may depend on your particular database engine.